# How to convert a user input number to a vector on matlab?

Tags: matlab

I'm using an input function for a user on Matlab to input a 7 digit number, but how do i take their inputed number and convert it to a 7x1 matrix?
Thanks.

Comment: Show us what have you tried and where the problem is.

Comment: Try `double('1234567') - '0'`

Comment: Why do you want to convert ? Give input as a 7x1 matrix instead. e.g `input('Enter 7x1 matrix =')` and then give input as, for example, `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]`

Answer (score 1):

If there are spaces between the numbers, you can write:

```
with_space = input('Enter No.','s');
d = str2num(with_space)
```

which will result in:

```
Enter No.>> 1 23 456
d =
     1    23   456
```

If you want to break a number to digits, you can write:

```
no_space = input('Enter No.','s');
d = str2double(regexp(no_space,'\d','match'))
```

which will result in:

```
Enter No.>> 1234567
d =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
```

Or use @Rotem trick from the comments: `d = double(no_space) - '0'`